Kafka partioning key difference between Python and Nestjs
In my infrastructure I have multiple microservices with multiple language communicating over Kafka. In my Kafka I have multiple partitions and to keep consistency I use a key when I push messages so that messages with the same key go to the same partition.
It works well when different Nestjs microservices communicate between them. Same different Python microservices.
But if a Python service and a Nestjs one use the same key it does not go to the same partition.
Here is my Netsjs code using ClientKafka from @nestjs/microservices:
private client: ClientKafka;
...
private sendMessage(topic: string, message: any, partitionKey: string): void {
  console.log('key', partitionKey);
  this.client.emit(topic, { key: partitionKey, value: message });
}

Here is my Python code using Producer from confluent_kafka:
def send_message(topic: str, message: str, partitioning_key: str):
    producer = Producer(...)

    producer = get_kafka_producer()
    producer.produce(topic, key=partitioning_key, value=message.encode("utf-8"), callback=delivery_callback)

    producer.poll(1)
    producer.flush()


Could you try encoding your keys both in nest and python in utf-8 encoding

The key in Kafka is a client implementation that hashes the key and % the number of the partitions of the topic.
Therefore different clients might use other hash algorithms in kafkajs that's murmur as mentioned in their docs, while at conflunet_kafka it's murmur2_random.
This might be the difference, you can always override the default partitioner
